# Net::SFTP::Foreign - rput fails (sort of) if target dir exists

Tags: perl, ssh, perlnetssh

[http://metacpan.org/pod/Net::SFTP::Foreign](http://metacpan.org/pod/Net%3a%3aSFTP%3a%3aForeign)

```
my ( $user, $password, $host ) = @_;
my ( $source, $dest ) = '/whatever';
my $sftp = Net::SFTP::Foreign->new(
    user     => $user,
    host     => $host,
    password => $password,
    more     => [ -o => 'StrictHostKeyChecking no' ]
);
$sftp->rput(
    $source, $dest,
    overwrite => 1,
    on_error =>
      sub { print $sftp->error; }
);
```

If $dest exists on $host, rput's on_error always fires and $sftp->error is "Remote directory '/whatever' already exists"

Despite the error, rput carries on and recursively copies the dir, but on the taget host it'll get copied *under* /whatever, instead of *over* /whatever. i.e. I end up with /whatever/whatever.

This serves as a crumby workaround if done before the rput, but I don't actually want to remove the destination dir:

```
$sftp->rremove( $dest );
```

Anyone have any idea what I'm doing wrong? WOuld I be better of globbing all of the files I want to transfer and then do a foreach $file (@glob_result) { $sftp->put ( yada, yada ) };? That seems inefficient and error prone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That error is expected, just ignore it.

Regarding your files being transferred to `/whatever/whatever`, I am unable to reproduce that problem, at least with the [development version](https://metacpan.org/module/SALVA/Net-SFTP-Foreign-1.70_08/lib/Net/SFTP/Foreign.pm) of Net::SFTP::Foreign.

What do you get when you set `$Net::SFTP::Foreign::debug = 2|4|64|4096|8192|32768` ?

Comment: Hmm, you're right. I can't reproduce the /whatever/whatever for a simple test program. I'm not sure what I'd done when I observed that behavior.

Comment: Ok, so now my on_error sub checks for that message and ignores it. Other errors will stop my program. Thanks for your reply!

Answer (score -1):

The source should ./* and the destination ./.

```
my ( $source, $dest ) = ('/whatever/*','/whatever/');
```

I hope this works.